# unique_ptr vs class instance as member variable

Tags: c++, performance

There is a class `SomeClass` which holds some data and methods that operates on this data. And it must be created with some arguments like:

```
SomeClass(int some_val, float another_val);
```

There is another class, say `Manager`, which includes `SomeClass`, and heavily uses its methods.

So, what would be better in terms of performance (data locality, cache hits, etc.), declare object of `SomeClass` as member of `Manager` and use member initialization in `Manager`'s constructor or declare object of SomeClass as unique_ptr?

```
class Manager
{    
public:    
    Manager() : some(5, 3.0f) {}

private:
    SomeClass some;    
};
```

or

```
class Manager
{
public:
    Manager();

private:
    std::unique_ptr<SomeClass> some;
}
```

Comment: Using a pointer can't be better. But you should really benchmark it and see how it affects your application. It really depends on access patterns.

Comment: @juanchopanza Correct of course, since the `Manager` is in all probability a stable object. A pointer *could* be better, though, if the OP's "etc." includes moving around a lot.

Comment: In terms of compile time, go with the pointer so can use the PIMPL idiom. In terms of runtime performance: profile.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

#### Short answer

Most likely, there is **no difference** in runtime efficiency of accessing your subobject. But using pointer can be slower for several reasons (see details below).

Moreover, there are several other things you should remember:

1. When using pointer, you usually have to allocate/deallocate memory for subobject separately, which takes some time ([quite a lot if you do it much](https://stackoverflow.com/a/163765/556899)).
2. When using pointer, you can cheaply move your subobject without copying.

Speaking of compile times, pointer is better than plain member. With plain member, you cannot remove dependency of `Manager` declaration on `SomeClass` declaration. With pointers, you can do it with forward declaration. Less dependencies may result is less build times.

#### Details

I'd like to provide more details about performance of subobject accesses. I think that using pointer can be slower than using plain member for several reasons:

1. Data locality (and cache performance) is likely to be better with plain member. You usually access data of `Manager` and `SomeClass` together, and plain member is guaranteed to be near other data, while heap allocations may place object and subobject far from each other.
2. Using pointer means one more level of indirection. To get address of a plain member, you can simply add a compile-time constant offset fo object address (which is often merged with other assembly instruction). When using pointer, you have to additionally read a word from the member pointer to get actual pointer to subobject. See [Q1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7983652/how-much-does-pointer-indirection-affect-efficiency) and [Q2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14248898/is-a-pointer-indirection-more-costly-than-a-conditional) for more details.
3. [Aliasing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointer_aliasing) is perhaps the most important issue. If you are using plain member, then compiler can assume that: your subobject lies fully within your object in memory, and it does not overlap with other members of your object. When using pointer, compiler often cannot assume anything like this: you subobject may overlap with your object and its members. As a result, compiler has to generate more useless load/store operations, because it thinks that some values may change.

Here is an example for the last issue (full code is [here](http://pastebin.com/UrTcRBmP)):

```
struct IntValue {
    int x;
    IntValue(int x) : x(x) {}
};
class MyClass_Ptr {
    unique_ptr<IntValue> a, b, c;
public:
    void Compute() {
        a->x += b->x + c->x;
        b->x += a->x + c->x;
        c->x += a->x + b->x;
    }
};
```

Clearly, it is stupid to store subobjects `a`, `b`, `c` by pointers. I've measured time spent in one billion calls of `Compute` method for a single object. Here are results with different configurations:

```
2.3 sec:    plain member (MinGW 5.1.0)
2.0 sec:    plain member (MSVC 2013)
4.3 sec:    unique_ptr   (MinGW 5.1.0)
9.3 sec:    unique_ptr   (MSVC 2013)
```

When looking at the generated assembly for innermost loop in each case, it is easy to understand why the times are so different:

```
;;; plain member (GCC)
lea edx, [rcx+rax]   ; well-optimized code: only additions on registers
add r8d, edx         ; all 6 additions present (no CSE optimization)
lea edx, [r8+rax]    ; ('lea' instruction is also addition BTW)
add ecx, edx
lea edx, [r8+rcx]
add eax, edx
sub r9d, 1
jne .L3

;;; plain member (MSVC)
add ecx, r8d  ; well-optimized code: only additions on registers
add edx, ecx  ; 5 additions instead of 6 due to a common subexpression eliminated
add ecx, edx
add r8d, edx
add r8d, ecx
dec r9
jne SHORT $LL6@main

;;; unique_ptr (GCC)
add eax, DWORD PTR [rcx]   ; slow code: a lot of memory accesses
add eax, DWORD PTR [rdx]   ; each addition loads value from memory
mov DWORD PTR [rdx], eax   ; each sum is stored to memory
add eax, DWORD PTR [r8]    ; compiler is afraid that some values may be at same address
add eax, DWORD PTR [rcx]
mov DWORD PTR [rcx], eax
add eax, DWORD PTR [rdx]
add eax, DWORD PTR [r8]
sub r9d, 1
mov DWORD PTR [r8], eax
jne .L4

;;; unique_ptr (MSVC)
mov r9, QWORD PTR [rbx]       ; awful code: 15 loads, 3 stores
mov rcx, QWORD PTR [rbx+8]    ; compiler thinks that values may share 
mov rdx, QWORD PTR [rbx+16]   ;   same address with pointers to values!
mov r8d, DWORD PTR [rcx]
add r8d, DWORD PTR [rdx]
add DWORD PTR [r9], r8d
mov r8, QWORD PTR [rbx+8]
mov rcx, QWORD PTR [rbx]      ; load value of 'a' pointer from memory
mov rax, QWORD PTR [rbx+16]
mov edx, DWORD PTR [rcx]      ; load value of 'a->x' from memory
add edx, DWORD PTR [rax]      ; add the 'c->x' value
add DWORD PTR [r8], edx       ; add sum 'a->x + c->x' to 'b->x'
mov r9, QWORD PTR [rbx+16]
mov rax, QWORD PTR [rbx]      ; load value of 'a' pointer again =)
mov rdx, QWORD PTR [rbx+8]
mov r8d, DWORD PTR [rax]
add r8d, DWORD PTR [rdx]
add DWORD PTR [r9], r8d
dec rsi
jne SHORT $LL3@main
```