# Memory leak in a Student pointer Node list in C++

Tags: c++, memory-management, memory-leaks

I have a Node list that each Node contains a pointer pointing to a Student variable (this is a class), and a pointer pointing to next Node. Here is my code for insertAtTail.

```
void studentRoll::insertAtTail(const Student &s) {
    if (head == NULL) {
        this->head = new Node;
        this->head->next = NULL;
        this->head->s = new Student(s);
        this->tail = head;
    }
    else {
        this->tail->next = new Node;
        this->tail = this->tail->next;
        this->tail->next = NULL;
        this->tail->s = new Student(s);
    }
}
```

I used valgrind to debug, and I got:

```
==11106== 16 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1 of 2
==11106==    at 0x4C2D1CA: operator new(unsigned long) 
(vg_replace_malloc.c:334)
==11106==    by 0x402BE7: StudentRoll::insertAtTail(Student const&) 
(studentRoll.cpp:15)
==11106==    by 0x401CF1: main (testStudentRoll01.cpp:19)
==11106==
==11106== 16 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 2 of 2
==11106==    at 0x4C2D1CA: operator new(unsigned long) 
(vg_replace_malloc.c:334)
==11106==    by 0x402C5B: StudentRoll::insertAtTail(Student const&) 
(studentRoll.cpp:22)
==11106==    by 0x401E2C: main (testStudentRoll01.cpp:27)
==11106==
```

Can someone help me with it? I think there are some problems about:

```
this->head->s = new Student(s);
```

and

```
this->tail->s = new Student(s);
```

But I cannot delete them because I need these "Students."
And there are pointers point to "Students."

Thanks!!

Update: here is my destructor

```
StudentRoll::~StudentRoll() {
    Node *iter = head;
    while (iter) {
        Node *next = iter->next;
        iter->s->~Student();
        delete iter;
        iter = next;
    }
    head = tail = NULL;
}
```

Comment: *But I cannot delete them* -- What about deleting them when your program is about to terminate?  Or how about when the `studentRoll` object goes out of scope?  That is when you must delete them, else it is a memory leak.  What does your `studentRoll` destructor do?  Better yet, a [mcve].

Comment: Valgrind isn't telling you your bug is in insertTail, just that the leak was allocated there.

Comment: Could you add your destructor? This code looks alright, so you are probably not freeing the memory elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

> Can someone help me with it? I think there are some problems about:
>
> ```
> this->head->s = new Student(s);
> ```
>
> and
>
> ```
> this->tail->s = new Student(s);
> ```
>
> But I cannot delete them because I need these "Students." And there are pointers point to "Students."

This problem probably indicates that you should redesign your program. In C++, you should express ownership semantics and make clear what objects own what resources and are responsible for their cleanup. Ownership semantics in C++ are expressed via various pointer types:

If a certain, single object owns some heap memory, rather than using raw pointers and `new` and `delete` directly, use [`std::unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr). `std::unique_ptr` is better because it conveys your intent to readers and uses [RAII](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/raii) to help prevent memory leaks.

On the other hand, if an object does not own a piece of memory, use a reference or a raw pointer instead. (In the future, the C++ standard library may get a non-owning smart pointer.)

If your linked list data structure owns the student objects, it should be the one to deallocate them. In this case, use `std::unique_ptr`:

```
void studentRoll::insertAtTail(const Student &s) {
    if (head.get() == nullptr) {
        this->head = std::make_unique<Node>();
        this->head->next = nullptr;
        this->head->s = std::make_unique<Student>(s);
        this->tail = &*head; // Get a raw pointer
    }
    else {
        this->tail->next = std::make_unique<Node>();
        this->tail = &*this->tail->next; // Get a raw pointer
        this->tail->next = nullptr;
        this->tail->s = std::make_unique<Student>(s);
    }
}
```

Instead of using `std::unique_ptr`, another option would be to simply make `Student` a data member of your `Node` type. However, this decision may indicate different intent and have different implications. For example, if you wanted to transfer ownership of the `Student` object from the `Node` object to somewhere else, you should use `std::unique_ptr`. If you kept the `Student` object directly as a member, you might achieve a similar effect by calling the `Student`'s move constructor, but some of the semantics would still be different. For example, pointers to the `Student` would be invalidated. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/31724938/8887578 for more comparisons of the two approaches.

If the student objects outlive the linked list, it should not be their owner and would be better off taking a non-owning pointer to such an object. In this case, do not allocate new student objects, but take a pointer from somewhere else:

```
void studentRoll::insertAtTail(const Student* s) {
    if (head.get() == nullptr) {
        this->head = std::make_unique<Node>();
        this->head->next = nullptr;
        this->head->s = s;
        this->tail = &*head;
    }
    else {
        this->tail->next = std::make_unique<Node>();
        this->tail = &*this->tail->next;
        this->tail->next = nullptr;
        this->tail->s = s;
    }
}
```

I don't know the context of your program (e.g. if it is a school exercise for writing linked lists), but in serious code, you should use the standard library's `std::list` instead of rolling your own linked list. In many cases, however, a `std::vector` (similar to dynamically-grown array) is more appropriate than a linked list.

Additionally, instead of giving `Node` a parameterless, default constructor and then later assigning its `s` member, you should pass the student pointer to it in its constructor.

Comment: Yes, it is my school exercise. When I use `make_unique`, an error occurs and says it isn't a member of std... I don't know why...

Comment: @ShihengWang `std::make_unique` is in the `memory` header if you are using C++14 or later.

Comment: @ The Aspring Hacker I can not use C++14 since I can not modify the Makefile... Are there any other ways to solve it? Or do you need some more specific information from my code?

Comment: @ShihengWang `std::make_unique` is just a helper function that constructs a `std::unique_ptr`. If you can use C++11, you should just call a constructor of `std::unique_ptr` directly.